# OFFSET...FETCH not working on PATSTAT Online

Tags: mysql, t-sql

I am updating some queries from MySQL to T-SQL as PATSTAT Online has moved over.

The following worked fine in MySQL, returning 700,000 rows starting at row 700,001, ordered by appln_id:

```
SELECT *
FROM tls201_appln
ORDER BY appln_id
LIMIT 700000, 700000
```

However, the equivalent (I thought) in T-SQL returns ALL rows:

```
SELECT *
FROM tls201_appln
ORDER BY appln_id
OFFSET 700000 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 700000 ROWS ONLY
```

What am I missing?

Any pointers will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is correct.  This code should retrieve rows 700001 to 1400000, ordered by appln_id.  Offset-Fetch is new to SQL Server 2012 and the only thing I can think of is that this code is being run on an earlier version.  In that case I would expect a syntax error, but I am not familiar with PATSTAT online.